# oracle data pump export file keeps growing in size

Tags: oracle, datapump

I am using oracle data pump in a similar way:

```
USERNAME=myname
PASSWORD=pass
INSTANCE=dbinstance

QUERY='employees:"WHERE hire_date > TO_TIMESTAMP('0101','YYMM')"' 
PATH=/tmp/test
expdp $USERNAME/$PASSWORD@$INSTANCE directory=EXPORT_DIR tables=hr.employees query=$QUERY dumpfile=employees.unl content=data_only logfile=employees.log
```

My question is the following:
My table has 15 rows with few data inside.. Why does on the log file it displays that some thousands of rows are exported every time? It displays 29000+ rows exported. Also the damp file that it creates, it keeps getting bigger every time i run the query. It started from some kb and after many times running the export, it reached so far to the point where it creates 500+MB logfile.
That is not reasonable for me. Does this have to do with archiving data or something?
And if it does how do i stop it so that i don't produce so large damp files?

Comment: Your `dumpfile` parameter doesn't look valid - the file (and log) are created under the OS directory pointed to by the Oralce directory object  `EXPORT_DIR`. It also won't be happy if the dump file already exists, it won't append to it. What does your log file say is happening?

Comment: Dear Alex.. I have the oracle directory created from before and is pointing to the correct directory. I must have wrote it wrong. For the dumpfile=$PATH/employees.unl i have only dumpfile=employees.unl

Comment: As far as the logfile. It displays that The command is completed succesfully and that 29000+ rows were extracted + the size is 566MB

Comment: When i import the data using the impdp, 15 rows are inserted correctly as 15 rows had the table from before

Comment: Does it only refer to the `employees` table in the export log? And says *that table* exported 29k rows? That would be weird. Does the export estimate have a higher value? Are your stats up to date - and has table ever been that large, or always only 15 rows?

Comment: @Alex.. I found the cause of the error. I had a very good look on the log file. The table that the data was extracted belongs to different schema so it was exporting data from the other schema. Sorry for the confusion